# C# bool statement throws strange exception for seemingly unconnected double.parse(string)

Tags: c#, datetime, boolean

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to C#. Trying to learn via examples. So I've found myself a nice little calculator tutorial. Everything goes fine up to last moment, the code is working, but it doesn't take multi-digit input like `33`. There's a bool statement there for turning arithmetic operations on/off and tutorial instructor figured, that we should put `bool = false` before the number input/button press (in `button_Click`).

His code looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    double value = 0;
    string operation = "";
    bool operation_pressed = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((tb.Text == "0") || (operation_pressed == true))
           tb.Clear();

        operation_pressed = false;
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        tb.Text += "\n" + b.Content.ToString();
    }

    private void operator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        operation = b.Content.ToString();
        value = double.Parse(tb.Text);
        operation_pressed = true;
        equation.Content = value + " " + operation;
    }

    private void result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        equation.Content = "";
        switch(operation)
        {
            case "+":
                tb.Text = "\n" + (value + double.Parse(tb.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "-":
                tb.Text = "\n" + (value - double.Parse(tb.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "*":
                tb.Text = "\n" + (value * double.Parse(tb.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "/":
                tb.Text = "\n" + (value / double.Parse(tb.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void CE_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Text = "\n 0";
    }

    private void C_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Clear();
        equation.Content = "";
        value = 0;
    }
}
```

It compiles nicely. But when I try to input a multidigit number and follow it with a mathematical operator, it throws an exception for `value = double.Parse(tb.Text);` that states:

> When converting string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the `DateTime` object.

I'm so confused right now. There's no `DateTime` even involved! And I'm 100% positive, everything is like in the tutorial. What's going on? :/

Any help will be appreciated greatly!

**EDIT**

Screenshot of actual error:

[image: The error]

Comment: So you input the multidigit number and a math operator in `tb.text`??

Comment: I've never seen an exception message like that before.  Are you sure that's the actual error you're getting?  And that it's actually coming from that line?  I *highly doubt* `double.Parse()` is throwing that as an exception.

Comment: Try this  double someValue = double.Parse(tb.Text); value=SomeValue; do you still get the error in the Parse?Is the value property bound to an editor?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the error. There is some confusion here. Not sure what it is.

Comment: Thats just a general hint for problems that might throw a FormatException but not a hint for this concrete problem. Presumably you used the wrong decimal separator for the double value when entering the value into the TextBox.

Comment: Can you tell us what t the value of `sb.Text` is in the debugger when the exception is thrown?

Comment: tb not sb.  Good control naming seems to be a hard to master art form ;)

Comment: The DateTime stuff is a red herring. It's just a common reason for parsing exceptions, but not this one.

Comment: "What is with all of those "\n" entries in the `Text` field?  If you are completely new to software writing, this is a special value which means *Wrap the following text to a new line.*  Specifically, it is call the `Line Feed` character and, in Windows is usually preceded with an "\r" (which I won't discuss in a comment.)

Comment: Anyway, this could be throwing off the parser.  Your value needs to be a numeric string, with no additional special characters.  Regarding the error message, if you aren't using a standard, English localization of Windows, you've probably found an error in some of Microsoft's exception localization code.  I'm guessing this was a copy-and-paste error, copying the DateTime parser error, into the Double parser.

Comment: \n are there due to the design of textbox - it's overlayed with a label (named `equation` in the code) at the top, so I had to push the readings down.

Comment: if I remove `operation_pressed = false;' from `button_Click` and put it in the beggining of `result_Click`, there's no exeption and everything works fine; exept multidigit numbers - if I input '29' i get just '9'. 
Putting that bool in `button_Click` was tutor's idea, not mine, and it worked for him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're interpreting the debugger incorrectly.  This is *not* the error message:

> When converting string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

Notice how it's listed as "Troubleshooting Tips".  In the vast majority of cases, you can ignore it.  The error message itself is in a language I don't know, so I can't speak to what it says.  But a `FormatException` essentially means that you're trying to parse a value which can't be parsed.

Your screen shot cuts off some information, but what is the value of `tb.Text`?  Is it one of those `"+"` strings?  If so, then that's your problem.

`"+"` can't be parsed as a numeric value, because "+" isn't a number.

You can make your code a little more resistant to errors by using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.  Something like this:

```
double result;
if (!double.TryParse(tb.Text, out result))
{
    // couldn't parse
}
```

If the `if` block isn't entered, then `result` will contain the successfully parsed value.  If it *is* entered, then the value couldn't be parsed.  How you handle that situation is up to you.  An error message to the user, a default value instead of the parsed value, etc.  That's application logic for you to define.

The point is, `tb.Text` contains a non-numeric value which you're trying to convert into a numeric value.  Hence the error.

Comment: The thing is - it works, when `operation_pressed = false;` is in `result_Click`, but it doesn't (and goes boom) when it's in `button_Click`. And judging by the tutorial it SHOULD be there, to accept multidigit numbers as a values. It works for the guy who made the video tutorial I'm following.

Comment: @roonroon: "It works" and "it doesn't work" is a very broad and generic statement, and I'm afraid doesn't carry much value to the code.  I can't speak to the tutorial you're following or even what your application is intending to do.  But the specific exception happens because you're trying to parse a non-numeric string to a number.  However you can prevent that, you need to prevent it.  Maybe you're parsing the wrong value, maybe that input shouldn't allow non-numeric values, maybe some logic is incorrect somewhere else... I can't know.  It's up to you to understand the logic of your program.

Comment: @roonroon What is the value of tb.Text when it crashes?Is is an integer or not?Depending on your pc's language settings you may have to use an overload of TryParse.Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @David 'it works' mean that when i remove that bool from the button, there's no exeptions and no errors. Calculator works and performs well except taking multiple digit numbers (like '23'. When you put it in, you'll get just '3'). Other than that there's no problem. Everything converts fine and there are no issues concerning non integer values, language exeptions and such.
'It doesn't work' means that when I put that bool statement into button to try if it's going to fix multidigit issue, all goes wonky and all those exeptions start to happen.

Comment: @roonroon: This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with debugging.  Copying and pasting code, running the application, and *guessing* what might be wrong is not a very effective way to solve problems.  With the debugger you can place breakpoints in the code and step through the executing application, line by line, manually examining the run-time values of your variables.  That's how you get from "it doesn't work" to *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: Mea culpa, my humble appologies. It WAS `\n` after all. Thank You for Your persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in operator_Click event

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
operation = b.Text;
value = Convert.ToDouble(tb.text)
```

Comment: It says `Button b' doesn't have `.Text` definition :/

Comment: okay then use the same code you have , but just do conversion as I have mentioned.
e.g. value=Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` will throw the same exception as `double.Parse`.

Comment: you have '\n' inside tb.Text How would it get converted ?